# How to set attribute based on the previous value of this attribute in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I have a factory and a trait. I'd want to set attribute in factory and later modify this attribute using trait:

```
factory :photo_gallery do
  photos { PhotosGenerator.generate_10_photos }

  after(:build) do |photo_gallery|
    # set value of some other attribute based on value of photos attribute
  end
end

trait :non_broken do
  photos { photos.reject(&:broken?) } # raises `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`
end
```

As you see it raises `SystemStackError`. How can I set value of `photos` attribute in a trait based on value that was set for this attribute in factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional ignored attribute to factory and use it to access photos in trait:

```
factory :photo_gallery do
  ignore do
    temp_photos { PhotosGenerator.generate_10_photos }
  end

  photos { temp_photos }
end

trait :non_broken do
  photos { temp_photos.reject(&:broken?) } # OK
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not "filter" your photos collection in a trait. Instead yo should "build" only what you need.

```
trait :non_broken do
  # build non_broken photos only
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is recursive:

```
photos { photos.reject(&:broken?) }
```

Traits aren't like inheritance; you can't call the "super" implementation, instead whichever trait is applied last will be the only implementation that is used.

You'll need to completely redefine the `photos` attribute without referring to the previous implementation, something like this:

```
photos { PhotosGenerator.generate_10_photos(broken: false) }
```

Alternatively, you could use a callback, so that you're not redefining the attribute, you're changing it after it's been set:

```
trait :non_broken do
  after :build do |object|
    object.photos.reject!(&:broken?)
  end
end
```

Comment: Will callback in trait be run before or after callback in factory?

Comment: BTW I decided that adding additional ignored attribute is a cleaner way